# Intercepting wp_mail() to view contents

Tags: debug, wp-mail

I'm looking for a way to hook into the mail function before it sends so I can var_dump the output. **Are there any action hooks with the mail message that I can hook into?** I'm having trouble finding the `wp_mail()` function in core. Any other methods of debugging mail output would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first link on Google is to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ which says that wp_mail is in wp-includes/pluggable.php

It also has the full function source code showing that the first active line of the function is:

`$atts = apply_filters( 'wp_mail', compact( 'to', 'subject', 'message', 'headers', 'attachments' ) );`

... which suggests that if you hook into the filter you can capture all of those fields.

Additionally as it's a pluggable function you could also replace it with your own function doing whatever you want with the messages.